# How to move an item in a list two units down

Tags: python, slice

How do you shift an item in a list two units down?

Ex. Move the number '1' two units down.

```
>>> move([1,2,3,4])
[2,3,1,4]
```

Comment: Why would use do that with list slicing? Why not just `list_.insert(2, list_.pop(0))`?

Comment: `numpy.array([1,2,3,4])[[1,2,0,3]]` is one way...

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll go with what sweeyneyrod suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sweeneyrod pointed out no need for slicing:

```
def move (l, from_, to = 2):
    return l.insert (to, l.pop (from_) )
```